# EF many to many relationship, trying to convert SQL to LinqToSql c# query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to EF models and used to write a lot of stored procedures to produce data in my applications, but now we are using EF and models and I am sure there must be an easier way to work out results in this situation, at least I know how would I do it with simple SQL.

```
 Relationship defined like this :
        this.HasMany(c => c.Roles)
            .WithMany(r => r.Contacts)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("ContactRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("ContactId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });

        this.HasMany(c => c.Reports)
            .WithMany(r => r.Contacts)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("ContactReports");
                m.MapLeftKey("ContactId");
                m.MapRightKey("ReportId");
            });
```

SO the Contact has many Roles and the Role has many Contacts

Now what I have got yet that works is this :

```
        var roles = _context.Roles.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
        var contacts = _context.Contacts.Where(x => x.CustomerNumber == id).ToList();

        foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
        {
            _context.Entry(contact).Collection(c => c.Roles).Load();
            foreach (Role role in contact.Roles)
            {
                if (role.IsUnique == true)
                {
                    roles.Remove(role);
                }
            }
        }
```

And all I would wish for is something like this in `LinqToSql` :
I am sure there is an advantage getting all the data in one SQL statement right?

```
Select * from Roles
where Id not in 
(Select r.Id from Contacts c
join Customers cs on c.CustomerNumber = cs.CustomerNumber
join ContactRoles cr on cr.ContactId = c.Id
join Roles r on r.Id = cr.RoleId
where c.CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber AND IsUnique = 1)
```

So how can I write this in LinqToSQL c# query?
It is difficult because I don't have access to ContactRoles model and don't know how to do a `'not contains(1,2,3)'` on multiple role ids

```
var roles = from r in _context.Roles
            select r...;
```

I know I am lacking study but advise would be nice or I am back to stored procedures.

Comment: are you going to convert already existing Stored procedures to Linq query or what ?

Comment: yes that's what I want to do, convert that SQL to linqtosql, it would be great to be able to do that in code query so I wouldn't need that stored procedure

Comment: why don't you like SP?

Comment: because we moved to EF using models now so we don't write SP anymore in this project, that's a requirement

Comment: I think you're only looking for the `Include` method. By the way, LinqToSQL is not the same as Entity Framework.